# MYSQL restrict number of times a particular value can be in a field

Tags: php, mysql, database

I will try to explain this question as best I can.  My db has a row called "week" with a field called "status."  Status can have the following values:

Active
Completed
Future

There can be only one "Active" week row.  Future and Completed may occur multiple times.

So is there a way in mysql to make Active a unique individual value which can't occur in more than one row?

At this point the only way I can think of to do this is to use PHP to read in all the rows and loop through them to find if a row is set to Active, then prompt the admin to change that value before selecting another week as active.

Comment: Are you looking for a purely technical way to prevent it? Then you would have to add another column (e.g. `active`, maybe calculated by a trigger or formula or as a replacement) and a unique index for it. Setting two rows to "1" would then result in an error. But that would only be necessary if the user can directly edit values in the database. If the user uses php to edit the values anyway, you can do any kind of check and update you want to do before (or while) you set another row to active.

Comment: You can store ID of active record in other table, containing only one row. Or determine the status by comparing date in row and current date

Comment: Another column is a thought Solarflare, but a row can't have be Active and Completed, or Active and Future at the same time.

Comment: I meant something like this: add the column and a unique index. Add a `before update/insert` trigger that sets the value of this column depending on your `status` (`null` or `1`). This will result in an error if you try to add a second active row, so technically it would do the trick. But usually it is easier and cleaner to build this kind of logic into the application if the user doesn't have direct access to the database, because "multiple states, but one of it just once" is a rather complicated value (at least for a database). Or maybe change your value completely. E.g. if ...

Comment: ... all weeks before the active week are "completed"  and all rows after the active week are "future", these additional states are redundant (to not call them denormalized) and you could model (or interpret) you data differently. But you didn't provide enough information for that. Or about how that value is set to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looping in php on every rows you can just check if you have an active row.

`SELECT id FROM table WHERE 'active' = 1`

Or

`SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table WHERE 'active' = 1`

You have to do this before inserting.

You can have a bad luck and have a row set active between the check and the update.

If you want to have only one value you can create another table storing only the id of the active row. In this table you will always have only a single record.